# SQL Server 2018 : database email - exception message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (The operation has timed out

Tags: sql-server, database-mail

I am using SQL Server Management Studio V18. I would like to schedule a job in SQL agent, which will send some mail based on some condition. For that I have configured database account profile and I am trying to test the email. But email is not received. It is saying the below error. any help on this will appreciate.

> The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 1002 (2021-03-30T05:36:55).
> Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server (The operation has timed out

Comment: Please don't tag spam, none of these tags are related the the question you are asking here. I;ve corrected what I can, but you also should tag the Mail Server software you are using.

Comment: There is no SQL Server 2018 version - we have 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 and 2019 - take your pick

Comment: As for the error, it's telling you that, for what ever reason, the SQL Server instance/host can't communicate with the Mail Server; we don't have enough information to tell you more than that.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to either connect "in the clear" or use a custom or 3rd party program.  This (maddening) issue has been with SQL Server for over a decade and, for us, it was because of using a secure connection (time outs - some mail never sent - yada yada). Our email server gets the connection credentials, so it IS communicating with it - (handshaking), but there's a bug with SSL when it comes time to deliver the message.
Our solution was to create a CLR C# program that gets called and delivers messages correctly. You can look for a 3rd party emailer as well. SQL email will always disappoint.